# Rails - Mime not working for paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Paperclip, when I upload files like PPTX or DOCX, the content_type is showing application/zip which is a incorrect MIME type. Any suggestions for fixing mime types in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the mime type to /config/initializers/mime_types.rb?

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this. Is this from Rails or paperclip? Surprised there isn't a default file with populate options for all the MS Office type of files?

Comment: This is a rails thing, it allows for you to offer more options within the respond_to block. I typically don't use MS specific mime types because I can't garuntee that my users have the product necessary to open, I stick with CSV or TXT if doing an export. For a list of all the MS product mime types check this out: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

Answer (score 1):

try to use paperclip Model with this validation

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => [ 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' ]
```

append other in you initializer if you need .